# Please suggest solution for Crashing Swiffy converted swf to html5 on IPAD safari

Tags: javascript, ios, html, performance, flash

I have stuck at problem of crashing of swiffy converted swf file in html5
I am working on e-learning 
In my course I am integrating the swiffy converted html5 files

After viewing some pages the player in which i am loading html5 files gets crached

some times immediately after loading it gets crashed

I tried to destroy the old object of swiffy using destroy method and also made stage=null of previous file

So kindly suggest some solution for crashing problem of swiffy on IPAD_safari

And I want to also know how to convert swf into html if my file size is more than 1024kb

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have seen the same issue in e-learning sessions I've developed.  Did you ever find a solution?  I'm using Swiffy 6.0.1.